# How to display the current date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

In my view I want to display the current date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
<%= Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
```

Answer (score 27):

You could simply do (substitute in `Time` for `DateTime` if using straight Ruby -- i.e. no Rails):

```
DateTime.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

If you're using that format a lot, you might want to create a `date_time_formats` initializer in your `RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers` folder (assuming Rails 2), something like this:

```
# File: date_time_formats.rb
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :human => "%m/%d/%Y"
)
```

Which will then let you use the more friendly version of `DateTime.now.to_s(:human)` in your code.

Comment: This is the most elegant way to do it. Using strftime all over the place is messy.

Actually though you can just do something like this (less verbose)

```ruby
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:mdy] = "%B %d, %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:mdy] = "%B %d %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_and_year] = "%B %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:pretty] = lambda { |time| 
  time.strftime("%a, %b %e at %l:%M") + time.strftime("%p").downcase 
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that changes in config files only take effect after server restart, unlike changes in models,views and controllers.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use `.strftime`:

```
t = Time.now()
t.strftime("The date is %m/%d/%y")
```

This should give `"The date is 09/09/10"`. See [here](http://www.wetware.co.nz/blog/2009/07/rails-date-formats-strftime/) for a great list of the format codes for `.strftime`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the full year you could try 
`Time.now.strftime('%D')`