# Rails - friendly_id : how can i format the friendly_id parameter like a datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, format, friendly-id

i would like to use friendly_id with a datetime in id like that :
friendly_id :date

is there a way to configure the format the parameter of friendly_id (here :date) to have change the display ? (here better than "2010-05-09 00:00:00 UTC")

Comment: There are a lot of answers to similar questions like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677753/how-to-display-current-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-rails So when you know what you want to see, it is just a matter for formatting it.

Comment: Thank for your answer, i've edited my post to be more clarifier. I want to configure the format of the parameter :date of friendly_id.

Comment: Can you explan why you want to do this? There might be better ways because what you want is not the way its used to be and if you want to change this it can get compicated. Maybe we can solve the essential problem!

Comment: Sure, i have entry, one by date (sort of day report) and i want to have an url like localhost/reports/25-05-2010 instead of localhost/reports/831

Answer (score 1):

If you have an extra column above the standard created_at and updated_at, you can use it to make the friendly_id.

It won't work with the standard created_at column as this gets populated after the friendly_id callback meaning that the record isn't actually created.

If you do have a column say ... `report_date` with a type of datetime then you could do this ...

```
# app/models/report.rb  ## using friendly_id 3.x
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  # I recommend using a cache column as well.
  has_friendly_id :report_slug, :use_slug => true, :cache_column => 'cached_slug'
  before_create :set_report_date

  def set_report_date
    self.report_date = Time.now
  end

  def report_slug
    report_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
  end
end
```

Or like this in FriendlyId 4.x

```
class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :report_slug, :use => :sluggable
  before_create :set_report_date

  def set_report_date
    self.report_date = Time.now
  end

  def report_slug
    report_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
  end
end
```

All you need is a string column called slug on your model if using 4.x

By using before_create and the `set_report_date` method, you can ensure that the `report_date` value is only populated once (on create).

Some options for `strftime` can be found here: https://gist.github.com/1965714

Hope that helps.