# Add current date in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to add current date in rails form as below. I am not able to figure out how. kindly help

```
<div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :date_submitted, class: "required" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.date_field :date_submitted, Date.today, required: true, readonly: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the current date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677753/how-to-display-the-current-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is ideal, but if you have to have it in the form, maybe it makes more sense to set it in the controller>

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @modelname = Modelname.find(params[:id])
    @modelname.date_submitted = Time.now
  end
end
```

Given forms could be submitted at some future time/date, I don't think you want to set it in the form as the date/time could become stale/out of date.  instead, I would capture this on the create/update as such:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @modelname = Modelname.find(params[:id])
    @modelname.update(modelname_params.merge({ date_submitted: Time.now }))
  end

  private

  def modelname_params
    params.required(:modelname).permit(:fieldname)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a value to the `date_field`:

```
<%= form.date_field :date_submitted, value: Date.today %>
```

If you share the form between "new" and "edit" you can add a condition to display the default value (Date.today) or the recorded date:

```
<%= form.date_field :date_submitted, value: (Date.today if @my_object.new_record?)  %>
```

Comment: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: i dont want the date to change if i edit the form some other day

Comment: `@my_object` is an example for the answer, you need to replace it with the record object you pass to the form. Anyway, if you always need the default value, just do `value: Date.today` without any condition

Comment: **<%= form.date_field :date_submitted, value: (Date.today if @funding.new_record?), required: true %> **I am able to select any date. I just want the date when the application is submitted. and it should not change when i edit my application

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 has implemented a nice attributes API ([`ActiveRecord::Attributes::ClassMethods#attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) so if you wanted a default value for `date_submitted` it would be as simple as

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :date_submitted, :datetime, default: -> {Time.now}
end
```

Now when the `date_submitted` method is called on the object (e.g. via a form builder) it will show the current date/time of when the method was called.

Since this is just a default value if a different value is provided during instantiation e.g `SomeModel.new(date_submitted: "2018-06-19")` that value would take precedence over the default value provided.

That being said since you have decided that `date_submitted` is required and read only and you are setting this value, if you are using time_stamps on your model it might make more sense to just do something like

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  def date_submitted
    self.created_at.to_date #for just a Date
  end
end
```

Since the `created_at` timestamp will always represent when the object was created which seems to be identical to `date_submitted` in this case.